# Synchronize scrollviews in fragment (same scroll speed)

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, scrollview

I decided to make control like tablelayout with fixed columns (on the left) .. so I made my own class based on RelativeLayout. That class contains two scrollViews: _scrollViewLeft and _scrollViewRight (each of them contains tableLayout). Everything works fine (data is present, columns and rows are aligned, tables are same height) but scrolling one scrollView doesn't scroll the other. I dont know if the problem lies in the fact that control is placed in the Fragment inside ViewPager.

This is scrollView class that should make possible synchronizing two

```
private class MatrixScrollView : ScrollView
{
        public MatrixScrollView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
        {
            if (Tag.ToString() == "scrollViewLeft")
                _scrollViewRight.ScrollTo(0, t);
            else
                _scrollViewLeft.ScrollTo(0, t);
        }
    }
```

Just to make it clear: if you scroll scrollViewLeft in some direction line
    _scrollViewRight.ScrollTo(0, t);
executes - but it does nothing _scrollViewRight is left standing where it was before.

My control is based on [this](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-scroll-table-fixed-header-column.html)

Comment: Do both scrollviews have the same content?

Comment: No, they have different tablelayouts, based on the same source. Lets say List<string[]>. So the number of rows is the same and rows are of the same height - so tableLayouts are of the same height too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was probably some mixup with ViewPager or lifecycle and Tag property. So I passed instance of connected scrollView - and it worked.

```
public class MatrixScrollView : ScrollView 
{
    public MatrixScrollView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
        OverScrollMode = OverScrollMode.Never;
    }

    public void SetConnectedScrollView(MatrixScrollView connectedScrollView)
    {
        _connectedScrollView = connectedScrollView;
    }

    MatrixScrollView _connectedScrollView;


    bool _isTouchScroll = true;

    public void ScrollThisView(int l, int t)
    {
        _isTouchScroll = false;

        ScrollTo(l, t);

        _isTouchScroll = true;
    }

    protected  override void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
    {
        base.OnScrollChanged (l, t, oldl, oldt);

        if(_isTouchScroll)
            _connectedScrollView.ScrollThisView(l, t);
    }
}
```